# Django template == condition on string doesn't work

Tags: django, string, templates, exception, conditional-statements

I want to display in an email template some conditional informations but even if the `{{ error }}` confirms the value of my error is **list index out of range** , the condition is not applied and `else` is taken in account.

I send to my (email) template this:

**views.py**

```
try:
    [...]
except Exception as e:
    error_product_import_alert(
                {'order_increment_id': order_increment_id, 'product': item['sku'], 
                'error': e, 'request': request})
```

**error_product_import_alert()**

```
def error_product_import_alert(context):
    product = context['product']
    order_id = context['order_increment_id']
    error = context['error']
    sujet = f' Anomalie : Import SKU {product} ({order_id}) impossible 
       ({error})!'
    contenu = render_to_string('gsm2/alerts/product_import_ko.html', context)
    [...]
```

**email template**

```
<p>--{{ error }}--</p>
{% if error == 'list index out of range' %}
    <p><strong>Le produit est introuvable dans la base.</strong></p>
{% else %}
    <p><strong>Erreur inconnue : veuillez contacter l'administrateur.</strong></p>
{% endif %}
```

Maybe my error is so big that I even can't see it.
Is there one ?

Comment: The exception *when rendered as string* will look like that. But `e`/`error` is an *exception object*, which never matches a string.

Comment: So simple ! Thanks, I didn't think the `__str__` Exception was returned (is it that ?) and then didn't notice it was an object when printing it. Sending`'error': str(e)` to the template did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing an `Exception` to a string. This would not work in templates. Try doing the logic in your python function itself and return the error string that will be rendered in the template.

For example:

You should try:

`views.py`

```
try:
    [...]
except Exception as e:
    error = "Erreur inconnue : veuillez contacter l'administrateur."
    if e.args[0] == 'list index out of range':
        error = "Le produit est introuvable dans la base."
    error_product_import_alert({
        'order_increment_id': order_increment_id,
        'product': item['sku'], 
        'error': error,
        'request': request
})
```

`template`

```
 <p><strong>{{error}}</strong></p>
```

Comment: Now I understand, thanks. The thing I don't understand is if the representation of an object is its `__str__` (or maybe its `__repr__` that should also return a **string** ), isn't this one also a string and why can't it be compared with another str ?

Comment: The actual representation of the object is `__str__` method, that is used when the object is rendered in the template. Before rendering, it uses the actual object for computation.